# Java boilerplate if statements

Tags: java

I am working on a bigger project and I am a little bit tired of the null check. 
I have a MongoDB- entity (Document) and this one has a reference to another document. In almost every case I check if it is null anf if not than do something.
I know that there is the Options class in Java 8 - this is of course an improvement but is there any other approach to improve this boilerplate code. How you are handling this?

Comment: `if` is probably your best choice here... in java. we don't have elvis operator unfortunately. we can simulate it with some helper APIs, but it's not really helping cut down the biolerplate. see thread http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-September/006055.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases, Null Object pattern can be useful. [Wiki information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)